# DynamoDB Update item wothout any action. Full rewrite

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I need to rewrite almost all in complex item schema.

I can't find the way to rewrite it without actions.

I've found the only way to send old and new item attributes, delete all by using old attrs and then add all from new one.
And make it by Class: Aws::DynamoDB::Types::UpdateItemInput
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkforruby/api/Aws/DynamoDB/Types/UpdateItemInput.html

Does it have another method?

Scheme is like:

```
{
  "app_params": {
    "production_params": {
      "hard_time_control": true,
      "index_max": 300,
      "time_control": true,
      "weight_fix": 100,
      "weight_max": 200
    },
    "search_mx": "11g"
  },
  "client": "client_name",
  "dashboard": false,
  "data": true,
  "test_port": 123,
  "servers": [
    {
      "name": "server1",
      "port": 123,
      "search_type": "test"
    }
  ],
  "stock_port": 456
}
```

Comment: PutItem will completely replace an existing item, if that's helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to jarmod.
The decision is PutItem method
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkforruby/api/Aws/DynamoDB/Client.html#put_item-instance_method